# Probability of Win Rates

Tags: probability, statistics

If I have 5 trading strategies and these are their individual win rates and their independent events:

> Strategy 1: 0.704545455

> Strategy 2: 0.638554217

> Strategy 3: 0.729411765

> Strategy 4: 0.680555556

> Strategy 5: 0.6125

What's the probability three or more strategies win on a given day?

Comment: Please first edit in whatever you have tried so far, and where you are stuck in order to elicit appropriate help.

Comment: There are $\binom{5}{3} +\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}=  16$ combinations to win three or more strategies.